# "Add new discussion" Is Creating a Message Instead of a Discussion

Tags: discussion-board

When I click **New Item** > **Discussion**, it correctly creates a discussion.
[image]

However, when I click **Add new discussion**, it creates a message instead of a discussion.
[image]

Note that the default content type is a discussion.
[image]

Even if I uncheck **Visible on New Button** for Message, it does not solve the issue.
[image]

Any suggested fixes apart from recreating the list?

Answer (score 2):

I tried it on SharePoint 2013 (create new discussion board) and it works exactly the same. You can change the WebPart property Toolbar Type to "Show Toolbar" and from this the New Action create Discussion too.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update, I did not find other alternative solutions and I ended up having to re-create the discussion board.